# How can I create a graph in excel that uses multiple columns and does stacked columns?

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I need a graph that has multiple columns and also has stacked columns. Here is a photo to help illustrate what I am looking for: [Graph Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0cR.png) As you can see in the photo there are two graphs. I want them to become one I wanted the Stacked there to be a total of 2 columns for each data series. I want the front column to have Data C3:C14 with D3:D14 Stacked on top of it, Then a column in the back that has B3:B14.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can not so you have to cheat.
Can you upload the spreadsheet?

Comment: This may be a really stupid question to ask, I am farely new here, how do I upload my spreadsheet?

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question. It seems there is not that functionality on the forum so just upload to any storage site (e.g. Dropbox) and link to here

Comment: easy like ... @mondaymorning

Comment: Here is the link for the dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyc98ldvw8jujs7/StackOverFlow%20WS.xlsx?dl=0